# What library to use to connect to rest api?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

I need to connect to external REST API. Now i am using ktor lib and Coroutine but I'm wondering if there is a better library for this. I'm new in kotlin, so I need help to choose.

OkHttp, Retrofit or maybe somthing else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/retrofit-with-kotlin-coroutine-in-android/

Retrofit seems to be the most popular library.